# Date / time of Wikidot page Draft

Tags: wiki, legal

In a Wikidot page, I / the user has written some stuff which was saved into Draft.

This is (very) important, I need to get the time or even just the date that a page's Draft was saved.

Is there any way to get this information? Like a hidden webpage or functionality that can be enabled?

Or is there any JavaScript (or Chrome extension that I can use) that could retrieve this information?

Is there absolutely no way to get this? (even though the info is obviously saved in the server)